# adding LinkedHashMap in ModelAndView object and get it in jsp page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

In spring controller, can i add LinkedHashMap to ModelAndView object so that i can get that map in jsp page and can do further processing.Please suggest.

```
 mav.addObject("myList", myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a ModelAndView in your method, but String knows nothing about it. For Spring to go to the view specified in the ModelAndView, and use the model in the ModelAndView, the ModelAndView must be *returned* by the method:

```
public ModelAndView editATRRequest(ModelMap model,
                                   @RequestParam("ID") String Id) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("myData", model);
    ...
    mav.addObject("documentList", documentList);
    return mav;
}
```

And please, learn the JSP EL and the JSTL. You should never use scriptlets in your JSPs. Please also indent your code, to make it readable.

Comment: thanks but my question was how to read that documentList added in modelAndView object in jsp page, as i have almost no experience in JSTL and EL , please suggest if possible.@JB Nizet.

Comment: From scriptlets (which should NOT be used): the same way as you're doing it now. With the JSP EL: `${documentList}`

Comment: is below one correct: <% java.util.LinkedHashMap<Long,UserDTO> documentList = (java.util.LinkedHashMap<Long, UserDTO>)${documentList}; %>

Comment: No. You can't use the JSP EL inside scriptlets. Scriptlets contain Java code. What is correct (I repeat) is what you're already doing: `java.util.LinkedHashMap<Long,UserDTO> documentList = (java.util.LinkedHashMap<Long, UserDTO>) request.getAttribute("documentList");`

Comment: +1 for the scriptlet comment.  God I hate scriptlet.  Oh, and the other stuff is good too.